# After adding value in Dictionary (map) when I print the Dictionary its show all value same (value.data)

Tags: c#, dictionary

** after print Dictionary all values are same. Why?? Where is the problem??**
** after print Dictionary all values are same. Why?? Where is the problem??**
** after print Dictionary all values are same. Why?? Where is the problem??**
** after print Dictionary all values are same. Why?? Where is the problem??**

> In Dictionary I added Key as int and value as an object(Node)
> In Dictionary I added Key as int and value as an object(Node)
> In Dictionary I added Key as int and value as an object(Node)
> In Dictionary I added Key as int and value as an object(Node)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tree1
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node left, right;
    }

    public class NewNode
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        public Node createNode(int key)
        {
            node.data = key;
            //Console.WriteLine(key);
            node.left = node.right = null;
            return node;
        }

    }

    public class Print
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        public void inorder(Node root)
        {
            if (root == null)
                return;
            inorder(node.left);
            //Console.WriteLine(node.data+" ");
            inorder(node.right);
        }

    }

    public class BinaryTree
    {
        Node root = new Node();
        NewNode newNode = new NewNode();
        public Node createTree(int[] parent, int n)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Node> map = new Dictionary<int, Node>();

            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            {
                map.Add(i,newNode.createNode(i));
                //Console.WriteLine(map.Keys + " " + map[i].data);
            }

           
            foreach (var pair in map)
            {
                int key = pair.Key;
                Node value = pair.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(key + "/" + value.data);
            }
            

            root = null;

            for(int i = 0;  i<n; i++)
            {
                if(parent[i] == -1)
                {
                    root = map[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    Node ptr = map[parent[i]];
                    //Console.WriteLine(parent[i]);
                    
                    //Console.WriteLine(ptr.data);
                    if (ptr.left != null)
                    {
                        ptr.right = map[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ptr.left = map[i];
                    }
                }
            }

           
            return root;
        }

    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            int[] parent = new int[] { -1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4};

            BinaryTree binaryTree = new BinaryTree();
            Node root = new Node();
            root = binaryTree.createTree(parent, parent.Length);


            Print print = new Print();
            print.inorder(root);



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: `createNode` does not return a new node -- just the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a constructor in your node class.

> ```
> public class Node
> {
>     public int data;
>     public Node left, right;
>     
>      public Node(int data){
>        this.data = data;
>      }
> }
> ```

Then when you create a new Node, you can pass the value you want to be set as data.

> ```
> var newNode = new Node(value);
> ```

Comment: That's good to hear @mdzahidfesabelilla glad I could help